# Not able to access wordpress website publicly installed on azure VM having apache server as xampp

Tags: configuration, iis, virtual-hosts

I have installed the WordPress website on Azure VM using Apache Xampp server. I have changed the Xampp port to 8090 to avoid conflict with other applications.
I can access the website on localhost and also through a private IP address but not able to access it publicly. Can anyone give the solution to access the website publicly?